# Excel - Aggregating the same ID pairs with value subtraction

Tags: microsoft-excel

Source data : [image]

Result I am looking for : [image]

I would like a formula to do this for thousand of occurrences (always by pair, it is flow data). The smallest value should be subtracted from the larger. The line with the larger value should be the one that remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data sets are grouped by row in pairs, that is leveraged to identify and compare the values.  The formula checks if the first row of data is on an odd or even row.  Moving forward that is used to identify all the pairs.

`odd; even,` `odd; even,` `odd; even,` etc.
*or*
`even; odd,` `even; odd,` `even; odd,` etc.

##### Formula

1. The formula uses a named range `data` to make the formula easier to follow and maintain `$A2:$C1000`
2. There is basic assumption from the question that two members of a pair will never have equal values or that if they do they are not of interest. If they do, they will both be filtered out from the results since `x-x=0`.

```
=LET(
   rowOffset, IF(ISEVEN(ROW(INDEX(data,1,1))),0,1),
   newValues,
      MAP(INDEX(data,,3), LAMBDA(r,IF(r<>"",
         IF(ISEVEN(ROW(r)+rowOffset),
             IF(r>OFFSET(r,1,0),r-OFFSET(r,1,0),0),
                 IF(r>OFFSET(r,-1,0),r-OFFSET(r,-1,0),0)),0))),
   newData, HSTACK(INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(data,,2), newValues),
   FILTER(newData, INDEX(newData,,3)>0))
```

[image]

##### Notes

```
Line |  Code
-----+------------------------------------------------
  1  |  =LET(
  2  |   rowOffset, IF(ISEVEN(ROW(INDEX(data,1,1))),0,1),
  3  |   newValues,
  4  |      MAP(INDEX(data,,3), LAMBDA(r,IF(r<>"",
  5  |         IF(ISEVEN(ROW(r)+rowOffset),
  6  |             IF(r>OFFSET(r,1,0),r-OFFSET(r,1,0),0),
  7  |                 IF(r>OFFSET(r,-1,0),r-OFFSET(r,-1,0),0)),0))),
  8  |   newData, HSTACK(INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(data,,2), newValues),
  9  |   FILTER(newData, INDEX(newData,,3)>0))
```

| Line | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| #1 | Use the **[LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)** function to allow storing intermediate calculations, and defining names in the formula. |
| #2 | `rowOffset` equals `0` or `1` <sup>The [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) formula (line 4) assumes first pair members are on even numbered rows.</sup> <sup>`rowOffset` offsets the row number as needed</sup> <sup>[INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) is used to identify row 1 column 1 of the `data` range `INDEX(data,1,1)`</sup> <sup>[ROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) gets the row number of the indexed cell `ROW(INDEX(data,1,1))`</sup> <sup>[ISEVEN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iseven-function-aa15929a-d77b-4fbb-92f4-2f479af55356) returns TRUE if the row number is even `ISEVEN(ROW(INDEX(data,1,1))`</sup> <sup>and finally [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) it's even then 0, or 1 for odd `IF(ISEVEN(ROW(INDEX(data,1,1))),0,1)`</sup> |
| #3 | Declare `newValues` to store the result of the [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function |
| #4 | [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function creates column of values **0** or the difference between a pair. <sup>[INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) is used to get the old values from the `data` in column 3 `INDEX(data,,3)`</sup> <sup>The indexed columns [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) into the [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function `MAP(INDEX(data,,3),`</sup> <sup>The [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) defines `r` to holds values mapped in `MAP(INDEX(data,,3), LAMBDA(r,`</sup> <sup>[IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) statement skips the rest of the [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) if the mapped value is blank `IF(r<>"",`</sup> |
| #5 | Check if `r` is the first or second member of the pair <sup>[ROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) gives us `r`'s row number `ROW(r)`</sup> <sup>`rowOffset` is added in case first members are on odd rows `ROW()+rowOffset`</sup> <sup>[ISEVEN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iseven-function-aa15929a-d77b-4fbb-92f4-2f479af55356) returns TRUE if `r`'s row + `rowOffset` is even `ISEVEN(ROW()+rowOffset)`</sup> <sup>[IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)'s `value if TRUE` = 1st member, & `value if false` = 2nd `IF(ISEVEN(ROW()+rowOffset),`</sup> |
| #6 | 1st member compares value to 2nd member `IF(r>OFFSET(r,1,0),r-OFFSET(r,1,0),0)` <sup>[IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) tests if `r` is larger than the value [OFFSET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) by 1 row below and 0 columns `IF(r>OFFSET(r,1,0),`</sup> <sup>"Value if true" is to subtract from `r` the value below `r-OFFSET(r,1,0)`</sup> <sup>"Value if false" is `0`</sup> |
| #7 | 2nd member compares value to 1st member `IF(r>OFFSET(r,-1,0),r-OFFSET(r,-1,0),0)` <sup>[IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) tests if `r` is larger than the value [OFFSET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) by 1 row above and 0 columns `IF(r>OFFSET(r,-1,0),`</sup> <sup>"Value if true" is to subtract from `r` the value above e `r-OFFSET(r,-1,0)`</sup> <sup>"Value if false" is `0`</sup> |
| #8 | Build array `newData` from column ID 1, column ID2, and `newValues` <sup>[INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) gets the first column ID1 from `data` range `INDEX(data,,1)`</sup> <sup>[INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) also gets the second column ID2 from `data` range `INDEX(data,,2)`</sup> <sup>[HSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) combines indexed columns and `newValues` into a 3 column array `newData`</sup> <sup>`HSTACK(INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(data,,2), newValues)`</sup> |
| #9 | [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) array `newData` where 3rd column values > 0 `FILTER(newData, INDEX(newData,,3)>0))` |